# How do I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from a matrix using the Accelerate framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, linear-algebra, accelerate-framework

I have a function written in C to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but it takes a lot of CPU time since I am calling this function several times as part of another algorithm. According to Apple the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/performance/accelerateframework.html) can be used to find eigenvalues from matrices very fast using BLAS and LAPACK.

As I am new to the Accelerate framework, so which functions should I be using to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a square matrix?

Answer (score 4):

That depends a bit on the character of the matrix that you wish to decompose.  There are different routines in Lapack for symmetric/Hermitian matrices, banded diagonal matrices, or general matrices.  If you have a general matrix (w/ no particular structure) you will need to use the generalized Schur decomposition routines.  The routines are divided between single and double precision and between matrices with real or complex elements - as is all of Lapack.

The general eigen-problem solver routines are named: ***SGEEV CGEEV DGEEV ZGEEV*** where the S = single precision real, C = single precision complex, D = double precision real, Z = double precision complex.

IBM has a good online reference for lapack, [here's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r1.essl100.doc/am501_hsgeev.html) a link describing the above routines.

Good luck!

Paul

Comment: This is a good answer. I would emphasize that LAPACK functions in the Accelerate framework expect data in **column-major** order (as in Fortran), rather than row-major order (as is conventional in C). This is easily the biggest source of confusion and error for newcomers.

Comment: Very good point warrenm - getting that mixed up can be a headache.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i'll read and try to implementing